# Getting whitelabel error for Spring-boot application

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, thymeleaf

I'm new to Spring boot development please help me out with following error

Directory structure(including structure of important files only )

```
src
   -main
       -java
           -com.example.handlingformsubmission
               -Greeting.java
               -GreetingController.java
               -HandlingFormSubmissionApplication.java
       -resources
           -templates
               -greeting.html
               -result.html
           -application.properties
   -test
       -java
           -com.example.handlingformsubmission
               -HandlingFormSubmissionApplicationTest.java
   -build.gradle
```

While execution I encountered this error when I run it on browser

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Wed Mar 11 19:08:44 IST 2020
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

and when I terminate or stop the application

```
Execution failed for task ':HandlingFormSubmissionApplication.main()'.
> Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 143
```

Currently I'm using springboot version 2.2.2

Here is my code

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.2.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'war'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

HandlingFormSubmissionApplication.java

```
package com.example.handlingformsubmission;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example.handlingformsubmission.greeting"})
@SpringBootApplication
public class HandlingFormSubmissionApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HandlingFormSubmissionApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

GreetingController.java

```
package com.example.handlingformsubmission.greeting;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;

@Controller
public class GreetingController {

    @GetMapping("/greeting")
    public String greetingForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("greeting", new Greeting());
        return "greeting";
    }

    @PostMapping("/greeting")
    public String greetingSubmit(@ModelAttribute Greeting greeting, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("greeting", greeting);
        return "result";
    }

}
```

application.properties

```
server.port=8000
```

greeting.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head> 
    <title>Getting Started: Handling Form Submission</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Form</h1>
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/greeting}" th:object="${greeting}" method="post">
        <p>Id: <input type="text" th:field="*{id}" /></p>
        <p>Message: <input type="text" th:field="*{content}" /></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

result.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head> 
    <title>Getting Started: Handling Form Submission</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Result</h1>
    <p th:text="'id: ' + ${greeting.id}" />
    <p th:text="'content: ' + ${greeting.content}" />
    <a href="/greeting">Submit another message</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do the logs say? Be good to see the exception

Comment: @Thomas__ I'm unable to figure out the error. I'm beginner in this course

Comment: Please read why you [should not post screenshots of code or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors).

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Comment: I think you'll want to include the directory structure of your code -- and also the specific URL that you are attempting to hit with the browser.

Comment: @nobar I've added the directory structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't specified in the question, but I'm guessing that you want to perform a `GET http://localhost:8000/greeting`

I won't fix your form, but the **404** can be resolved by fixing your `@ComponentScan`, for example...

```
// wrong: '.greeting' excludes the 'GreetingController'
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example.handlingformsubmission.greeting"})

// fixed: specifies a valid path that includes the controller
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example.handlingformsubmission"})
```

Once you fix this, you will be able to move forward and address the next issue:

> There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error,
>   status=500). An error happened during template parsing (template:
>   "class path resource [templates/greeting.html]")

---

*You can also fix this by removing the `@ComponentScan` entirely -- it isn't required for this initial scenario.*